# How do I use a custom shape as the background for a bootstrap dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm fairly new to Bootstrap.

I currently have a working dropdown menu, but I want the actual dropdown to not just be a rectangle. I have a shape image that I want to use as background. I'm trying not to create a dropdown menu from scratch, if possible.

Something like this. Please ignore the black lines. Note the shape of the dropdown box is not a regular rectangle.

[image: Dropdown]

I looked at the bootstrap code and I can't seem to figure it out. I'm thinking I should set my image as the background and have the dropdown appear on top of it, without the default borders... Is that possible?

TIA for any ideas and help!

Comment: If you at least add your visual goal that would help you and putting codes will get your questions answered pretty quick.

Comment: Why is the suggested answer from the question I added above not working for you?

Comment: @prettyInPink I am just trying it right now. It actually works, thanks!